# A characterisation of continuous function $f:X\to Y$.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, continuity, metric-spaces, solution-verification

Consider the condition that $f:X\to Y$ is continuous iff $f^{-1}(B^o)\subset (f^{-1}(B))^o$.Now the proof can be done as follows,it is obvious that $f^{-1}(B^o)\subset f^{-1}(B)$,this is true for any function.See the diagram below:
[image]

Now take interior on both sides $(f^{-1}(B^o))^o\subset (f^{-1}(B))^o$,Now $B^o$ is open in $Y$,so $f^{-1}(B^o)$ is open in $X$ by continuity of $f$ and so $(f^{-1}(B^o))^o=f^{-1}(B^o)$,so $f^{-1}(B^o)\subset (f^{-1}(B))^o$.We are done.I think this is the shortest way to prove the $(\implies)$ part.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I think it looks good. Perhaps that "take interior on both sides" part is a bit sketchy. Not that I doubt the argument's validity but, rather, the phrasing.

Comment: @pegasus this is actually a common way of putting it, which works for both closure and interiors: $A \subseteq B$ implies $\overline{A} \subseteq \overline{B}$ and $A^\circ \subseteq B^\circ$; this is what the OP means, I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The argument is correct, and could be summarised as follows: let $B \subseteq Y$.

Then $$B^\circ \subseteq B$$ (by definition of interior), and as $f^{-1}$ preserves inclusion:

$$f^{-1}[B^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[B]$$ and this implies by a standard property of interior (monotonicity), and because inverse images of open sets are open:

$$f^{-1}[B^\circ] = f^{-1}[B^\circ]^\circ \subseteq f^{-1}[B]^\circ$$

which shows the inclusion.

Conversely, if this identity holds for all $B$, and $O \subseteq Y$ is open (so $O^\circ =O$) we have that

$$f^{-1}[O] = f^{-1}[O^\circ] \subseteq f^{-1}[O]^\circ \subseteq f^{-1}[O]$$

which implies that $f^{-1}[O]^\circ = f^{-1}[O]$ and $f^{-1}[O]$ is open, and so $f$ is continuous.

Comment: why the downvote?